# Как понять что хранить в сторе, а что в реактовском стейте? Где хранить текст, введенный в textarea?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Подскажите. Как понять что хранить в сторе, а что в реактовском стейте?

Вот например у меня есть  textarea , где я набираю текст и при нажатии на кнопку делаю запрос на сервер и отправляю данные. Текст, который я ввожу в textarea(около 120 символов максимум) где хранить в данном случае? Можно ли такое хранить в сторе?
это обрабатывать с помощью redux-form (они есть уже в проекте)?

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от многих факторов, но в целом, если данные из инпута очень локальные данные и не используются больше нигде, то их можно сохранить и просто в state компонента. Если же состояние этого инпута важно для приложение или эти данные нужны другим компонентам, или вы, например, используете `redux-persist` для сохранения стора приложения, то скорее всего лучше хранить в сторе.

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Кстати, локальный стейт можно тоже хранить в редаксе, в таком случае он будет поддерживать все middleware и т.д.: `redux-local`, `redux-fractional`, `redux-ui`